# Python make an if statement change a variable

Tags: python

Ok, so, im trying to make my code ask for your date of birth and then with that figure out exactly (to the second) your age
My code

```
 import datetime

 now = datetime.datetime.now()
 day = int(input("What day was you born DD/MM/YYYY (DAY ONLY)"))
 month = int(input("What month was you born? DD/MM/YYYY (MONTH ONLY)"))
 year = int(input("What year was you born? DD/MM/YYYY (YEAR ONLY)"))
 yearold = now.year - year
 print("You are", yearold, "years old")

 monthold = yearold * month
 monthsold = now.month + monthold
 print("You are", monthsold, "Months old")
```

The problem is it will add one year, so it needs to ask has your birthday passed yet, and if it hasn't edit the value for yearold -1
for instance, birthday 10/10/2000
would say 14 when infact its 13

Comment: Let python do the calculations for you, use `datetime.timedelta()` http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Comment: This isn't relevant to your question, but your line monthold = yearold * month is wrong.  If you're born in January (month 1) and 12 years old, that will say they are 12 months old.  I think you want monthold = yearold * 12, and then I think you want monthsold = monthsold + now.month - month to actually calculate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily check if the birthday has already passed or not by doing this:

```
birthday_passed = now > datetime.datetime(now.year, month, day)
```

Anyway, you can use the `.delta` method of the `datetime.datetime` object which will give you pretty much directly whatever you need.

I see you are starting with programming at a pretty good age... have fun!

Comment: Uhh, doesn't it need to be datetime.datetime(now.year, month, day), and not year, month, day?  This will just check if the person has been born..

Comment: Yup, you are right... my initial test checked if the birthday happened prior to "now" =)

Comment: What is the behavior of this on (now.year, 2, 29) in a non-leap year?

Comment: `datetime(2005, 2, 29)` raises `ValueError: day is out of range for month`